# @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") is throwing Forbidden

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` to restrict the method access to only for the admin for that I have write the follwoing method

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class BasicAuthController {
        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        @DeleteMapping(path = "/deleteUser/{userId}")
        public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable int userId) {
            authenticationService.deleteUser(userId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok((""));
        }

}
```

My configuaration call is like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true,securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

 @Autowired
 private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
    // user for matching credentials
    // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()      
     .headers()
      .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
      .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate", "/api/v1/register","/api/v1/basicauth").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
         .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
         .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
         .deleteCookies("my-remember-me-cookie")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository(){
 JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
 tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
 return tokenRepositoryImpl;
}
```

}

I am calling my service using the below code

```
    delete(userId: number) {
        debugger;
        return this.http.delete(`/api/v1/deleteUser/${userId}`);
    }
```

I am getting

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

[image]

Comment: authenticating (your request) with role `ROLE_ADMIN` will help/overcome this. (where is user/password/role assignment/sso token?)

Comment: try with  `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` . [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize)

Comment: @R.G  `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` is also getting the same error

Comment: how have you configured the roles in your application ? Is it `ROLE_ADMIN`

Comment: yes, I have configured the roles and the logined person contains ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: Please share the `UserDetailsService` code where you are loading the user and role details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208922/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-ravanam-and-r-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was based on this [tutorial](https://www.techgeeknext.com/spring/spring-boot-security-token-authentication-jwt)

The `JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal()` uses `JwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)` to set the user credentials upon successful validation of the token . The logic didnt set the `GrantedAuthorities` and resulted in authorization failures down stream.

Setting the GrantedAuthorities correctly , fixed the method level authorization issues.